# Count occurrence when 2 values are in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Lets say we sell mobile contracts for different products.
client A bought an iphone 11 the first contract ends on 2023 05 01 but A has another contract starting on 2023 05 01, so this is a auto rolling contract.

Client B bought iphone 10, the contract ended on 2023 02 01 and its a one off contract, but the client decided to buy another contract on 2023 03 01. this is a manual contract.

I just wanted to do for a given Product, if the end date is equal to the start date for the same product but in a different row. then its a auto rolling contract.

| Product | Start Date contract | End Date contract |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Iphone11 | **2023 05 01** | 2023 06 01 |
| Iphone11 | 2023 01 01 | **2023 05 01** |
| Iphone10 | 2023 03 01 | 2023 05 01 |
| Iphone10 | 2023 01 01 | 2023 02 01 |

I want to create a column to say ok iphone 11 has a auto contract and it repeated 1 time already.

| Product | Start Date contract | End Date contract | Auto contract | Occurance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Iphone11 | **2023 05 01** | 2023 06 01 | yes | 1 |
| Iphone11 | 2023 01 01 | **2023 05 01** | yes | 1 |
| Iphone10 | 2023 03 01 | 2023 05 01 | no |  |
| Iphone10 | 2023 01 01 | 2023 02 01 | no |  |
| Iphone12 | **2023 03 01** | 2023 04 01 | yes | 2 |
| Iphone12 | **2023 02 01** | **2023 03 01** | yes | 2 |
| Iphone12 | 2023 01 01 | **2023 02 01** | yes | 2 |

Comment: And if someone decides to (manually) buy another contract the day after the previous contract ended?

Comment: how do we know when a contract is auto?

Comment: And how is the occurrence of 2 calculated?

Comment: And if someone decides to (manually) buy another contract the day after the previous contract ended?  Then it shouldnt be counted over an auto contract, as the pricing will  be different.

Comment: ow do we know when a contract is auto? if the contracts ends but start another contract on the end day

Comment: And how is the occurrence of 2 calculated?  - there are 2 auto roll contracts after the first contract for iphone 12

Comment: "And if someone decides to (manually) buy another contract the day after the previous contract ended?" 
"Then it shouldnt be counted over an auto contract, as the pricing will be different."

Then please include the pricing details in your example, along with the logic that should be used to determine the difference between an auto rolling contract and a one off contract started the day following the end of a previous contract.

Comment: the pricing doesnt matter in my case, it just needs to be for a given Product, if the end date is equal to the start date on other row for the same product, its a auto rolling contract